# Creating a list in python using the same string but with different values attached to it

Tags: python, list, bitcoin, nonce

Before I ask my question I would just like to let you guys know that I am very new to Python so bear with me! :)

Anyway here is my question:

I am writing a bit of code for fun which calls an `API` and grabs the latest Bitcoin Nonce data. I want to be able to save the past few nonce value within my code itself.

Someone suggested I do this using a list. I have done this however every time a new nonce value comes out it just replaces the original value in the list as opposed to adding a new one.

Does anyone have an ideas as to what I am doing wrong or if there is a better alternative?

Thanks a lot! :D

```
from __future__ import print_function
import blocktrail, time

def code():

    client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
    address = client.address('x')

    latest_block = client.block_latest()

    nonce = latest_block['nonce']

    blockhash = latest_block['hash']

    print(nonce)

    noncestr = str(nonce)

    noncelist = []
    noncelist.append(noncestr);
    print(noncelist)
    time.sleep(60)

while True:
    code()
```

Comment: How do you suppose we tell you what you're doing wrong if we can't see your code?

Comment: I accidentally submited the thread without putting in the code. Updated now.

Comment: Please edit the question and indent your code properly. Indentation is not an option in python

Comment: Hi @Joshua; you have plenty of answers but i though you might like to learn about Python [mutable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=mutable).

Comment: @bufh I will read through this now, thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `noncelist` to an empty list each time in the function so obviously you only keep one value in it that you append on the next line, you would need to declare the list outside the function and pass the list in as an argument,  using a class may be a better approach making the list an attribute.

```
import blocktrail, time
class Bit():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nonce_list = []
    def run(self):
        while True:
            client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
            address = client.address('x')
            latest_block = client.block_latest()
            nonce = latest_block['nonce']
            blockhash = latest_block['hash']
            nonce_str = str(nonce)
            self.nonce_list.append(nonce_str)
            print(self.nonce_list)
            time.sleep(60)



Bit().run()
```

If you want to continually run the code you should probably daemonize the process, also the function continually calling itself is really not a good idea

If you are going to use a function, pass the list in and loop in the function just calling it once:

```
def code(noncelist):
    while True:
        client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
        address = client.address('x')
        latest_block = client.block_latest()
        nonce = latest_block['nonce']
        blockhash = latest_block['hash']    
        print(nonce)   
        noncestr = str(nonce)
        noncelist.append(noncestr)
        print(noncelist)
        time.sleep(60)


code([])
```

If you just want unique nonce's use a set to keep track of what has been added, I made created an example of using a class with multiple attributes, you will need to catch more possible exceptions:

```
import blocktrail, time


class Bit():
    def __init__(self, key, secret, net, retry_fail=1, update=60,max_fail=10):
        self.nonce_list = []
        self.seen = set()
        self.key = key
        self.secret = secret
        self.net = net
        self.key = key
        self.retry_fail = retry_fail
        self.update = update
        self.max_fails = max_fail

    def connect(self):
          return blocktrail.APIClient(api_key=self.key, api_secret=self.secret, network=self.net, testnet=False)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.max_fails:
                break
            try:
                client = self.connect()
                latest_block = client.block_latest()
            except blocktrail.exceptions.MissingEndpoint as e:
                self.max_fails -= 1
                print("Error: {}\n sleeping for {} second(s) before retrying".format(e.msg, self.retry_fail))
                time.sleep(self.retry_fail)
                continue
            nonce = latest_block['nonce']
            if nonce not in self.seen:             
                self.nonce_list.append(nonce)
                self.seen.add(nonce)
            print(self.nonce_list)
            time.sleep(self.update)
```

The key,secret and net are required, you can pass the other or use the defaults:

```
Bit("key","secret", "net").run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will look at this method also. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No worries, using a class will allow you a lot more flexibility, I would run the code as a service daemonizing the process so if it crashes it will be restarted

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks a ton. This community is amazing!

Comment: If I wanted to avoid having duplicate nonces in my list what would be the  best way to do that? Perhaps an if else statement or?

Comment: You could use a set to store all the nonces and check the set before adding to your list. I will edit when i get back on my comp

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks a bunch, this has really helped my learning and understanding of Python, you are a brilliant example of just how amazing this community is!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. It is just a rough example of how using a class can give you a lot more flexibility

Answer (score 2):

You are emptying the list then appending what do you expect:

```
noncelist = []
noncelist.append(noncestr);
```

It can be like this :

```
noncelist=[]
while True:
    code(noncelist)
```

**Modified code:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import blocktrail, time

def code(noncelist):

    client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
    address = client.address('x')

    latest_block = client.block_latest()

    nonce = latest_block['nonce']

    blockhash = latest_block['hash']

    print(nonce)

    noncestr = str(nonce)

    noncelist.append(noncestr);
    print(noncelist)
    time.sleep(60)
noncelist=[]
while True:
    code()
```

More appropriate way would be:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import blocktrail, time

def code():

    client = blocktrail.APIClient(api_key="x", api_secret="x", network="BTC", testnet=False)
    address = client.address('x')

    latest_block = client.block_latest()

    nonce = latest_block['nonce']

    blockhash = latest_block['hash']

    print(nonce)

    noncestr = str(nonce)
    time.sleep(60)
    return noncestr 
noncelist=[]
while True:
    noncelist.append(code())
    print noncelist
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes right  and your answer is great hats off :)